# How to build only specified assets into assetbundle in unity

Tags: unity, c#, modding, assetbundle

I have searched through the few results pertaining to this particular question, but haven't found any results that work. A simple rundown of what i am looking for is to be able to make a single asset bundle of specified assets in order to be able to make an automated process for what the mod system i am making for the project i am working on.

there are two ways I can think of that would be able to do this;

1. build specified resources and assets into an assetbundle
2. build everything in a specified folder into an asset bundle

all of what i have been able to find regarding this either wouldn't allow me to make the automated process i need or builds the all of the assetbundles and they have to be defined manually before hand.

Any resources or suggestions to this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some one might like to write an answer on using the Unity Addressable Asset system: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.5/manual/index.html

Answer (score 1):

After the advent of the [Asset Bundle Browser tool](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/AssetBundles-Browser) many things have become easy. Like you can get the dependency of the asset or you can manually drag and drop the asset in asset bundle. 
[image]

Comment: This is great.  Didn't know about this.  It says though that: "AssetBundle Manager is deprecated for Unity versions 2018.2 and higher. It is no longer available from the Asset Store [...] If you use Unity version 2018.2 or higher, see documentation for Addressable Assets."

Comment: Well i am using it in unity 2019. Maybe anything else has introduced by unity for this.

Comment: Yes you are right new replacement is Addressable Assets. Thanks for the info.

Comment: If you happen to upgrade to Addressable Assets (and it does what you'd expect and what the OP asked) then please post back with that as an answer so I can reward it the bounty. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not possible to exclude individual assets apart from scripts.  To exclude a script you can try following this advice: https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/208456906-Excluding-Scripts-and-Assets-from-builds

```
#if (UNITY_EDITOR) 
... your class/code ...
#endif
```

To exclude a directory (of scripts) which I assume also works with other assets such as images, you can use a symlink to the directory.